# Laravel multiple routes with 1 request?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I would like to optimize some requests, and handle requests like an batch insert. For example:

Instead of sending 100 Requests, i would like to perform only 1 request, containing the data and the method + url.

Example data:

```
{
    data =     {
        address = dsfgdfgsdfg;
        name = Gaddafi;
    };
    method = POST;
    path = "/Group/store";
}, {
    data =     {
        address = "dsfgsdfgfg dsadsadgfdsg";
        name = Grashoff;
        remoteID = 1;
    };
    method = PUT;
    path = "/Person/update";
},
.......
```

Is this possible to handle with 1 Request? And can i call my route from an another route?

Comment: You don't call a route from another, whenever you need that it means that you have to create a service/factory/library/class/somethingWithCode that you can inject on your controllers and reuse that logic

Comment: Thanks - i thought already that there is no solution for this. Would be fine, because ill already got that routes.

Comment: You can call another route from existing route using return Redirect::to('another_route_name');

Comment: I dont want to Redirect to another route - i would like to use an batch process to handle all routes.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel using resourceful routing. It has various methods for handling multiple http requests such as '`post`','`put`','`delete`','`get`'.

You can create separate routes for separate requests. But do not combine them to one.

You can bunch specific routes using [Group](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing) Routes.

You can call second route from first route and also send params to second route.

```
Redirect::route('second_route')->with('data', $data)->with('method',$method)->with('path',$path);
```